# Django aggregation max overrides values in query

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm trying to show some data using django database-abstraction.

I need to show total cars this year and its total.

My attempt:

```py
Cars.objects.filter(car__updated__year=datetime.now().year).values("car_id")).annotate(total=Sum("quantity")).values_list("title", "quantity").aggregate(Max("quantity"))
```

My expected result is:

```
{
    "cars": {
        "title": "toyota",
        "quantity__max": 8,
    }
}
```

But the `.aggregate(Max("quantity"))` overrides "title" and I receive this:

```
{
    "cars": {
        "quantity__max": 8,
    }
}
```

Without `.aggregate (Max (" quantity "))` the values ​​appear (except total, of course).

Comment: Not very clear from the query what you want. You annotated `total` but did not add it to the values list. Also, aggregate usually only returns the value you're calculating and not a queryset. In this case, I would just order by -quantity and pick the first object which should have max quantity.

Comment: You're right. I was using it wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to [aggregate information in a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/).  The `aggregate()` method just yields the summary, NOT the rest of the information in the queryset.  From your expected result, you should probably be using `annotate()` instead, which will add your aggregated value to the queryset values.

Comment: Actually I was using the aggregate in the wrong way. Many thanks =)